# MissingAuthenticationToken error while calling Amazon Route53 API PHP

Tags: php, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am trying to call `'ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest'` API of Amazon route53, but getting "Missing Authentication Error" everytime. I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.
Can some one please take a look at it?
Below is my code:

```
    $AWSAccessKeyId = "##########";
    $SecretAccessKey = "#################";
    $Timestamp = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT';

    $Signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256",$Timestamp,$SecretAccessKey));
    $AuthenticationToken = "AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWSAccessKeyId.", Algorithm=HmacSHA256,Signature=".$Signature;
       $headers = array(
          'X-Amzn-Authorization: $AuthenticationToken',
          'x-amz-date: $Timestamp',
          'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8',
        );

    $endpoint = 'https://route53.amazonaws.com/2012-12-12/hostedzone/######/rrset';

    $session  = curl_init($endpoint);                       // create a curl session
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);              // POST request type
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest); // set the body of the POST
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    // return values as a string - not to std out
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $responseXML = curl_exec($session);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra space in `$AuthenticationToken`. There shouldn't be one between the comma and "Algorithm". Other than that, I can't see anything else that looks wrong.

However, I'd suggest using the [Route53 client provided by the AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-route53.html) since they already have the authentication scheme implemented and tested, and will stay up-to-date if the authentication scheme of the service changes in the future.

Comment: Headers passed were incorrect, it should be like _'X-Amzn-Authorization:'. **$AuthenticationToken**,
         'x-amz-date:'. **$Timestamp**,_. Anyways as suggested by you I would rather prefer AWS SDK for PHP. Thanks!!